# Phaser moving sprites

Tags: phaser-framework

I have a few sprites, which are arranged horizontally. Used physics engine is P2. In update loop I setup velocity for each sprite:

```
sprite.body.velocity.x = 150;
```

Then I clear shapes for each sprite and load my custom polygon:

```
sprite.body.clearShapes();
sprite.body.loadPolygon('physicsData', 'sprite1');
```

After I load polygons, sprites start to move with different speed (different images). Why this happened? When I don't load polygons - everything works fine, sprites move with the same speed.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it has to do with polygons, that is, when creating them. But I do not understand something, you say that they both move at different speeds? Are they in contact or not? Because I have implemented a simple code from the Phaser examples and both polygons move at the same speed without being in contact logically.

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.CANVAS, 'phaser-example', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update, render: render });

function preload() {

   game.load.image('contra2', 'contra2.png');
   game.load.image('bunny', 'bunny.png');

   //   Load our physics data exported from PhysicsEditor
   game.load.physics('physicsData', 'sprites.json');

}

var contra, bunny;

function create() {

   //   Enable p2 physics
   game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.P2JS);

   contra = game.add.sprite(400, 300, 'contra2');
   bunny = game.add.sprite(100, 300, 'bunny');

   //   Enable the physics body on this sprite and turn on the visual debugger
   game.physics.p2.enable(contra, true);
   game.physics.p2.enable(bunny, true);

   //   Clear the shapes and load the 'contra2' polygon from the physicsData JSON file in the cache
   contra.body.clearShapes();
   contra.body.loadPolygon('physicsData', 'contra2');

   bunny.body.clearShapes();
   bunny.body.loadPolygon('physicsData', 'bunny');

   //   Just starts it rotating
   game.input.onDown.add(function() { start = true; }, this);

   cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

}

function update() {

   contra.body.setZeroVelocity();
   bunny.body.setZeroVelocity();

   if (cursors.left.isDown)
   {
       contra.body.moveLeft(200);
       bunny.body.moveLeft(200);
   }
   else if (cursors.right.isDown)
   {
       contra.body.moveRight(200);
       bunny.body.moveRight(200);
   }

   if (cursors.up.isDown)
   {
       contra.body.moveUp(200);
       bunny.body.moveUp(200);
   }
   else if (cursors.down.isDown)
   {
       contra.body.moveDown(200);
       bunny.body.moveDown(200);
   }

}
```

[Examples of P2 Polygons](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/p2-physics/load-polygon-2)

[Examples of P2 Movements](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/p2-physics/world-move)